# Как задать переменную извне для PHP функции с html кодом

Tags: php, html

Есть, например, такая функция на PHP:

```
function Content() { 
echo '<center><div class="content"></div></center>';
}
```

А как сделать так, чтобы записать все таким образом:

```
function Content() { 
echo $Somehtmlcode;
}
```

Comment: казалось бы, все что требуется - почитать [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php)?

Comment: Да, я именно эту статью и читал, использовал global и $GLOBALS, но не помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$str = 'Что-то';
echo content1($str);


function content1($html) { 
    return $html;
}

// Или так (но так делать плохо)

$str = 'Что-то';
echo content2();


function content2() {
    global $str; 
    return $str;
}

// Или вообще так 

$str = 'Что-то';
echo content3();


function content3() {
    return $GLOBALS['str'];
}
```

Comment: @lovo предпочтительно использовать первый вариант из моего примера _(передавать параметр)_

Comment: $Con = '<center><div class="content"></div></center>';
echo Content();
function Content() { 
return $GLOBALS['Con'];
}
И заработало. Сделал методом №3, спасибо большое!